# jQuery Load() and remote js file

Tags: jquery, load

jQuery 1.11.1
I am loading a form into a div, which is inside a tab. The form submits through AJAX to a PHP file.
Some jQuery functions, including the AJAX routine, need to be accessed by both the main program and the loaded form, so I created a js file, which is called up by both, since the form would not otherwise be able to access the javascript in the main file.

I am having problems troubleshooting and one of those problems may be that I am really not sure what directory I am in.
I am suspecting it may not be finding the DBFunctions.php file, as the server is not receiving a request. However, I changed the url to the full path and it is still failing. click code works okay and the form serializes okay. Then, nothing.

**Main File**

```
<div>
    <div id="UtilButtons">
        <div>
            <a class="btn" id="AddAdmin" href="javascript:void(0)">Add Program Admin</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**pAddPA.php**

```
<div class="SaveButton" id="ProgPAReg" data-formname="AddPA">Register</div>
```

**jQueryEdit.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#AddAdmin").click(function()
    {
        $("#UtilButtons").hide("slow");
        $("#ReturnButton").show();
        $("#AddPAFile").show();
        $("#AddPAFile").load("include/pAddPA.php?PubCode="+PubCode);
    });
    // ======================================== //
    //        S A V E  F O R M  D A T A         //
    // ======================================== //
    $('.SaveButton').click(function ()
    {
        var Sec  = this.id;
        var Name = $("#"+this.id).data('formname');
        var Form = $("#"+Name);
        var Data = Form.serialize();
        Data = Data + "&Sec="+Sec;
        console.log(Data);
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url:  "http://{path to file}/DBFunctions.php",
            data: Data,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data)
            {
                // Result message
            }
        });
    }   
});
```

**DBFunctions.php** (Just because someone will probably request it ... Never gets here.

```
session_start();
#====================================================
include("../include/connect.php");
$Conn = mysql_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DBName, $Conn) or die(mysql_error());
#====================================================
$Log = array();
$Error = array();
$Message = "";
$ErrorCount = 0;
switch($_POST[Sec])
{
    case "ProgPAReg":
    {
        // Save to database
        echo json_encode(array("Message"=>$Message, "Log"=>$Log, "Error"=>$Error));
    } break;
}
```

I'm not really sure whether the loaded file thinks it is in its' local directory or the calling program (which would be good to know), but I put the full url path in for the PHP processing file anyway, so that shouldn't make a difference. Since both the main program and the loaded program are using the same js file (jQueryEdit.js), I tried removing that file and testing which, of course, caused things not to function in the relative file.

If there is a request going out to the server, it is not getting it. Web Console Network shows nothing. the console.log shows that the file is properly serialized.

Comment: Hello there, if you're using chrome - have you tried using the dev tools, it can be accessed by hitting F12. Go to the `Network` tab, then, go to your website (don't close the dev tools yet) - do the action. After that, you should see a new line under network running. Check it out. If no new line is up, you should check `Console` tab.

Comment: You did not fully read the description? This is why I am puzzled. The AJAX is simply doing nothing. By the way, FireFoxes Web Console is much easier and intuitive to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was really puzzling her is that I could see no send happening from AJAX to the server. I still don't know why that is. It started working. But I wasn't getting a response. One place I never thought to look was the include file I had at the top of the page that held several functions. That file was pointing to the wrong directory. But, when it was not found, no error was produced. Then, when the main file tried to access a function, it simply failed. Again, no error, so nothing was being returned. Henceforth, I will check first if my includes exist.